# How to audit Windows patch level off-site?

Tags: patch-management

I would like to audit different Windows servers and desktop machines off-site using configuration output generated previously on the machines (e.g. output of the systeminfo command).

Previously I used Windows-Exploit-Suggester, but it is not working since Microsoft stopped updating their *Microsoft Security Bulletin Data* since April 2017.

I checked [WUA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387290.aspx), but as far as I understand it only checks the locally installed system.

Comment: What stops you from using WUA locally on your off-site machines? Don't you have any means to connect to them?

Comment: I would like to leave minimum footprint on the machines. Analysing only the output of some of the built in system commands make the process more portable, safe, lightweight and transparent.

Comment: How is WUA not "portable, safe, lightweight and transparent"? Whatever you mean by that all

Comment: Wsusscn2.cab is more than 200 Mb. Sometimes we are not able to deploy big files on systems, or files at all. In other cases we are not permitted to run scripts on the system.

Comment: Easiest way I could come up with is: fully patch a machine, export all patches via PowerShell to a file, compress it, build script to decompress + compare + log the output. Won't become simpler than that, I suppose, if you won't use applications with agents and so on